# Won't dual boot Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a DVD it won't boot. It is installed along side Windows XP. Windows XP boots with no option to boot Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

IF you fail to see the Grub:- Insert a Ubuntu 12.04 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:

`$sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt` # XY is the drive, eg. sda or sda1

`$sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

`$sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`

`$sudo chroot /mnt`

`$grub-install /dev/sdX`#X is drive number

`$update-grub`

Reboot. Lemme know if it doesn't work as intended.